# What is this type of ambiguity called?

Tags: terminology, ambiguity

There are a number of sentences that create a paradoxical-seeming ambiguity. I'm not sure what the name for this phenomenon is, and it'd be great if someone could help me out.

Examples include:

-"I don't know what I don't know." (tautologically). "But I do know what I don't know!" you protest. "I don't know if the Riemann Hypothesis is true."

-"I don't know where the closest BestBuy is." But if in fact the closest BestBuy is the one at the Palisades Center mall, and you do know where that store is, then it would seem that you do know where the closest BestBuy is, you just don't know *that* it's the closest one. (I guess one should have said "I don't know **which** the closest BestBuy is". But if you don't know which one is closest, you also don't know where the closest one is.)

-"I don't know who the man behind the curtain is." But the man behind the curtain is your father. So you don't know who your father is. ("But I do know who my father is" you protest.)

I suspect it's a kind of scope ambiguity.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This might not be a full answer, because I'm not sure if it covers your first example, but the second and third example definitely involve the [de re and de dicto distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_dicto_and_de_re), which is indeed generally analyzed as a scope ambiguity.

Comment: This might be better answered over on [philosophy.se]